# How to convert Number to Date type in angular?

Tags: angular7

I write an application with angular client side and asp .net Web api server and sql database, and in the client side(angular) I want to get the current date (Date.now()) to variable type Date (to save it in the datbase in type datetime)

I tried to convert it but I didn't found any convert function that do that .
my code is:

`theDate:Date = Date.now();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no functions in Date class that returns Date, so you can save the date as nvarchar in SQL and get the date as string in angular using the function

`toLocaleDateString()`

and if you want to get the current date use:
`(new Date).toLocaleDateString()`